# Invalid Authenticity Token during login form submission

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-authorization

**I understand about the error:**

```
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken
```

After a year or so, I am back to my old rails project which is using `Rails 2.3.8`.
Everything was fine. Server started but when I submit the login form, the error appeared.
The same project was working a year ago. Don't know what gone wrong.

Someone suggested in other posts to comment out the line `protect_from_forgery` in `application_controller.rb` but that doesn't seem to be a good idea as it may remove the error but will be prune to forgery attacks.

At first glance it seems to be some session issue which is old enough and is not cleared.

To cope up with sessions, I run the following command -

```
rake db:sessions:clear
```

I started the server and again the same problem.

After seeing the lot of posts, still don't know how to resolve. Any ideas ?

Comment: Hvae you tried clearing your browser's cache? Also, does your app uses caching?

Comment: I tried mozilla and chrome, cleared cache and started server but the same error. Yes I see the file `session_store.rb` that is having `ActionController::Base.session = {:key => 'app key', :secret => 'app secret'}`. Is that something to do ?

Comment: I also have session.rb with the line - `before_save :associate_session_to_admin`. The method is- `def associate_session_to_admin
    self.admin_id ||= self.match.id
  end`

Comment: I replaced the above lines in `session_store.rb` with `ActionController::Base.session_store = :active_record_store`, restarted the server and got some other sql exception related to session id not found. Then I again change back to key secret pair and started rails server from eclipse and error gone. Strange but it worked now.